# How to find max value for rows of n

Tags: excel, max

I have below data with grouping variable ("Date") and a value variable ("Value"):

```
Date        Value

2/1/2014    7
4/4/2014    8
6/7/2014    8
8/10/2014   88
3/1/2015    87
4/4/2015    65
7/7/2015    55
9/10/2015   43
```

I want to extract the maximum value for rows of 4 such that I have the maximum values of 88 (cuz first 4 rows) and 87 (the next 4 rows).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, in **D1** enter:

```
="B" & (ROWS($1:1)-1)*4+2 & ":B" & (ROWS($1:1)-1)*4+5
```

and copy down and in **E1** enter:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT(D1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Column **D** defines the data groups and column **E** gives the max for each group.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is located at `A1:B9`; enter this formula in `C2` and copy till last row of data:

```
=IF(MOD(ROWS(A$2:A2),4)<>1,"",MAX(B2:B5))
```

[image]